# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined - works first time, but get this error on subsequent calls

Tags: javascript, php

I have a PHP system which generates a form with a DIV that contains drop down lists. ALso in teh form is a image which has a onclick attribute which calls a JavaScript, passing in a string of values from the drop downs.

The first time the button sis clicked it works fine, but thereafter nothing happens.

After some investigation I found that there was a JavaScript error when onclick was firing:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

The code snippet as as follows:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="show_hide('advsearch');">Show / Hide Advanced Search Options</a>
<div id="advsearch">
<form name="sortjobs">
<br>
<table><tbody><tr>
    <td><label>Distributors: </label></td>
    <td><select class="sortjobs" name="disties">
        <option value="All">Show All</option>
        <option value="103">Test Dist One</option></select></td>
    <td><label>Resellers: </label></td>
    <td>    <select class="sortjobs" name="resellers">
            <option value="All">Show All</option>
            <option value="2609">  Test REseller </option></select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>

<label style="width:400px;"></label>
<a href="javascript:showUser(document.sortjobs.disties.value+'_'+document.sortjobs.resellers.value);">
<img src="search2.png" onclick="showUser(document.sortjobs.disties.value+'_'+document.sortjobs.resellers.value);"></a>
</form></div>
```

In the JS:

The "showUser" function is:

```
function showUser(str)
{
xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
if (xmlHttp===null)
 {
 alert ('Browser does not support HTTP Request');
 return;
 }
var url='livesearchenqs.php';
url=url+'?q='+str;
url=url+'&sid='+Math.random();
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;
xmlHttp.open('GET',url,true);
xmlHttp.send(null);
}
```

As I said, when the main page is first loaded (or refreshed), selecting a drop down value and clicking the "Search" image works fine. Subsequent clicks have no effect, giving the error, which is an the line :

```
   <img src="search2.png" onclick="showUser(document.sortjobs.disties.value+'_'+document.sortjobs.resellers.value);"></a>
```

The error is on the elements being referenced.
As I understand it the "Uncaught TypeError" error occurs when the referenced field does not exist, usually due to a typo, but the pages work first time.

THis is really got me stuck. I saw some notes somewhere that he cause might be to do with  relative position between the declaration and teh reference. But checking the diff between the before and after page (before/after the first successful click) I cannot see a significant difference.

Also puzzling is that this seems to work when locally (XAMPP), but on the live 1and1 server we get the error.

Comment: I think the problem is that the second time you clicking the button the resellers or disties are undefined. Confirm that resellers or disties have value.

Comment: @Almis - the values are set the second time too.

Comment: lets say we have x.value, the above errors says that x is undefined so it cannot read property value of undefined. This means that you need to debug everything that have .value your problem is somewhere there. Can you give live example?

Comment: @Almis, unfortunately I cannot give the live site details as this page requires login info.

Comment: What `stateChanged` function does? Also it doesn't seem to make sense to call `showUser()` both in `img` and `a`, I think you can remove `onclick` attribure for `img` element.